# Proving that the given Context free grammar generates strings with unequal number of a's and b's

Tags: context-free, check-my-answer

Here is the grammar given on the wikipedia:

$$ 
   S \rightarrow T \;|\; U \\
   T \rightarrow VaT \;|\; VaV \;|\; TaV \\
   U \rightarrow VbU \;|\; VbV \;|\; UbV \\
   V \rightarrow aVbV \;|\; bVaV \;|\; \epsilon
$$

I can understand how $V$ generates strings with equal number of a's and b's. I want to prove that $T$ generates strings with more a's than b's. The case for U can be proven symmetrically.

Here is my attempt and doubt.

$P(0)$: Suppose $s$ is a string with one extra a. Let $s_1$ be the longest balanced prefix of s. Then $s=s_1 t$ where t necessarily starts with $'a'$. For otherwise t will have a non-empty balanced prefix and $s_1$ won't be the longest prefix. Hence $s = s_1 a s_2$ where $s_1$ and $s_2$ are balanced and derivable from $V$. hence s can be derived as $S \rightarrow VaV=>^* s_1as_2$.

$P(n)$ : Suppose $T =>^* w$, where w has $n$ extra a's than b's. Let s be a string with $n+1$. Let $s_1$ and $t$ be as above. Then $t = aw$. By construction, $w$ has $n$ extra a's and is derivable from T. Therefore $T \rightarrow VaT =>^* s_1aw$.

My doubt is what is the need for the rule $T \rightarrow TaV$

Comment: Perhaps it’s not needed…

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That's my thought as well. Can you confirm?

Comment: If you can generate all words in the language without using this rule, then it is not needed.

Comment: Ok, I'll take that my proof is correct and the rule is not needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> Here is the grammar **given on the wikipedia**:
> [...]
> $T \rightarrow VaT \;|\; VaV \;|\; TaV$
> [...]
> My doubt is what is the need for the rule $T \rightarrow TaV$

[Wikipedia said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Distinct_number_of_a%27s_and_b%27s):

> Omitting the third alternative in the rules for T and U doesn't restrict the grammar's language.

Comment: I totally missed it